# How to select a random row when 2 rows have an equal property

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing items in a priority order as such:

```
id  priority
1   1   
2   2   
3   3   
4   8   
5   3   
6   4
```

Currently I retrieve items (SQL Server) in priority order, although a random item when there are matching priorities using the following query:

```
select item 
from table
order by priority, newid()
```

This will return

```
id  priority
1   1   
2   2   
3   3   
5   3   
6   4   
4   8
```

or

```
id  priority
1   1   
2   2   
5   3   
3   3   
6   4   
4   8
```

So it's approximately 50/50 traffic

I now have a requirement to only retrieve one row of the rows when there are two matching priorities, for example..

```
id  priority
1   1   
2   2   
3   3       
6   4   
4   8
```

or

```
id  priority
1   1   
2   2   
5   3       
6   4   
4   8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`, presuming SQL-Server (because of `NEWID`):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Priority
                                        ORDER BY ID)
    FROM dbo.table t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

If these are all columns you could also use this sql:

```
SELECT MIN(t.ID) AS ID, t.Priority
FROM dbo.table t
GROUP BY t.priority
```

**Update** "No, I need to be able to get a random row when two (or more) priorities match"

Then i have misunderstood your requirement. You can use `ORDER BY NEWID`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Priority
                                        ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM dbo.table t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: thanks, that looks good!  These aren't all of the columns, there are quite a few joining tables but I wanted to keep it simple to get a quick answer

Comment: Also your second solution wouldn't work.  Using my example data above, that will always return id 3 for priority 3

Comment: @lisburnite: i thought that you wanted to know how you can ensure that you always get the same row of a priority-group. Both approaches will always return the lower ID, if you want the opposite use `DESC` on the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER`-clause or `MAX` at the `GROUP BY`

Comment: no I need to be able to get a random row when two (or more) priorities match.  So if it's queried 10,000 times for example 5,000 of the result sets will have one priority 3 and the other 5,000 will have the other priority 3

Comment: @lisburnite: then you could use `ORDER BY NEWID()`, edited my answer

Comment: yeh that's worked perfectly, thank you, going to save us thousands :)